# retrofit passing parameters in GET request from shared preferences

Tags: android, retrofit

I am working on android project that have to get list of questions sent by the user.
I am using retrofit to make the request and then display the questions in a `ListView`.  The problem is I have to pass the user id with the request which will be saved in shared preferences.  I need to know how to pass the parameters by retrofit:

```
import java.util.List;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.GET;

public interface QuestionApiInterface {
    @GET( "/getquestionsjson.php" )
    void getStreams( Callback<List<Question>> callback );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
public interface QuestionApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/getquestionsjson.php")
    void getStreams(@Field("userId") String userId,  Callback<List<Question>> callback);
}
```

I used `POST` because it better for sensitive data

Answer (score 0):

Look like that your web url is not a restful api link, so your process in `getquestionsjson.php` may use the query parameters, something like follow?

```
    www.xxxx.com/getquestionsjson.php?userid=5
```

If it is, you can use like the follow code to make the interface:

```
    @GET( "/getquestionsjson.php" )
    void getStreams(@Query("userId") String userId, Callback<List<Question>> callback );
```

In general, the retrofit interface making depend on your process in web(getquestionsjson.php), so you must know the parameters needed by the server, if the interface in web is post, plz use the style as meda`s answer.